# Raspberry Pi WiFi connection to Enterprise WPA2 WLAN

Tags: wifi

This is my first question here.

I want to connect my RPi to my company WLAN network but there are some problems and I am out of ideas to solve them.

1. The WLAN does not appear in the list of WLAN's in the GUI WiFi dropdown.
2. The network guys have given me a .pfx file and said that this is the certificate and key to connect to the company WLAN.
3. I know that the network uses TLS and does not need a username and a password, just the certificate should be enough?

Could someone please share the wpa_supplicant.conf file that would work with a .pfx certificate and uses TLS WPA2 enterprise WLAN network. Any help would be appreciated. I am losing hope.

Best

Comment: https://netbeez.net/blog/connect-your-raspberry-pi-to-wireless-enterprise-environments-with-wpa-supplicant/

Comment: @Dougie thank you! that is very helpful for clarifying my concepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to connect to your companies WLAN network using the `.pfx` certificate. You have given all needed information. The information to use them you can find with:

```
rpi ~$ man wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The important part is at the end. You are using **EAP-TLS** so you should have a client certificate and a server side certifcate included in the `.pfx` file, that must converted:

> CERTIFICATES
>   Some  EAP  authentication  methods  require  use  of  certificates. EAP-TLS uses both server side and client certificates whereas EAP-PEAP and EAP-TTLS only require the server side certificate. When client certificate is used, a matching  private  key  file has to also be included in configuration. If the private key uses a passphrase, this has to be configured in wpa_supplicant.conf ("private_key_passwd").
>
> wpa_supplicant supports X.509 certificates in PEM and DER formats. User certificate and private key can  be  included  in the same file.
>
> If  the user certificate and private key is received in PKCS#12/PFX format, they need to be converted to suitable PEM/DER format for wpa_supplicant. This can be done, e.g., with following commands:
>
> # convert client certificate and private key to PEM format
>   openssl pkcs12 -in example.pfx -out user.pem -clcerts
>   # convert CA certificate (if included in PFX file) to PEM format
>   openssl pkcs12 -in example.pfx -out ca.pem -cacerts -nokeys

It seems that you do not need option `private_key_passwd` because they told you there is no protection of the client certificate with an additional password.

To setup wpa_supplicant.conf you should start with the example given with:

```
# work network; use EAP-TLS with WPA; allow only CCMP and TKIP ciphers
network={
   ssid="work"
   scan_ssid=1
   key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
   pairwise=CCMP TKIP
   group=CCMP TKIP
   eap=TLS
   identity="user@example.com"
   ca_cert="/etc/cert/ca.pem"
   client_cert="/etc/cert/user.pem"
   private_key="/etc/cert/user.prv"
   # private_key_passwd="password"
}
```

Maybe you will need some try and error but it should do.

Comment: awesome, thank you so much. You are a life-saver!!!, I will get it a try tonight and give you feedback.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work. I extracted client and server certificates (ca.pem & user.pem) from the .pfx file. Then I extracted the "user.key" which has a key just like SSH key used in github. Sometimes the RPi says "no wireless interfaces found" and sometimes it shows all the available WLAN networks with the WPA ones grayed out but does not connect to the work_wifi even if I reboot multiple times :/

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue for my automation solution Ive provided to Industry.
Mostly It depends on what type of security is implemented in WPA-Enterprise WiFi settings done by IT admins while setting up RADIUS server and WiFi setup.
Its difficult to guess so mostly it looks like impossible to connect to few Enterprise networks without any help from IT department.

Recently I found another way to do this. Changing options doing trial and error from wpa_supplicant is tedious job. **wpagui** is better solution to try different options for Enterprise WiFi connection.

Its mostly not present in latest Rasbian OS and can be installed and run by :

```
sudo apt-get install wpagui
sudo wpa_gui
```

I'll test this in next few days and report here.

Comment: What does **wpa_gui** do? Have you had a look at **wpa_cli**? Is there a difference beside the graphical user interface?

Comment: @Ingo, this is not about difference. This is about ease of use. If you know about WPA/WPA2 - Enterprise Setup, Its very difficult to get exact settings if its not already known. Enterprise WiFi connection parameter has multiple possibilities. Might be different as per system admins choice. Most of the time WiFi infrastructure is managed centrally by some agency and its difficult to get proper technical support for this. So only way to to do this is try different options to make successful connection.