# How to disable Acess Point mode (Router/Repeater)?

Tags: pi-4, systemd-networkd, wpa-supplicant

I set up raspberry pi 4 with this [tutorial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge/89804#89804?newreg=5ece6c1383374a1faf53d88bc2246e4c) : Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge.

How do I turn off ap mode and how to enable it again?

When I plugged in ethernet port, the pi still broadcast wifi but there is no internet connection. (School ethernet port)

Also how to connect to wpa2 enterprise network with certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right you just want do stop the Access Point. This can simply be done with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

To start it again just do:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

This will only stop/start temporary. On boot up the AP will always start. To avoid this you have to **disable** the service. Then you have to **enable** it again.

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

This takes effect only after reboot. To disable/enable the service and stop/start it now you can execute:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable --now wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable --now wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

Comment: Thank you. What about when I plugged in the Ethernet, I can connect to the WiFi but there is not internet connection. How should I fix this?

Comment: Hi @Felix-LocLe, if this answer your question it would be nice if you could accept it with a click on the tick on its left side. Only accepting an answer will finish your question and it will not pop up again and again for years for nothing. The ethernet cable doesn't connect to the internet and doesn't matter. It is the WiFi uplink on **wlan0** that should connect to the internet router by WiFi and provide internet access. Check if the client connection on interface **wlan0** to the internet router is working.

Answer (score 1):

> This is an Answer to part of the Question "but the wifi bar is not working" which has since been deleted.

Because it uses [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-networkd) the new all-singing all-dancing network manager - which unfortunately is mind boggling difficult to use.

Raspbian uses `dhcpcd` and the network icon is a GUI front end to this, so it won't work if you disable `dhcpcd`.

> Also how to connect to wpa2 enterprise network with certificate?

You should be able to do this by manually editing `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` (or the particular wpa_supplicant you are using). There are examples of how to configure wpa_supplicant for enterprise networks on this site and these should work in the same way.

Comment: This wifi require to accept provided certificate, therefore I dont know how to set it up, i had read many post but I found no solution.

Comment: @Felix-LocLe I have never done this  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/96757/8697 may help, otherwise you should ask a new question specifically about this.